# In Scala, why can't I explicitly use a parameter type here?

Tags: scala, generics, lambda, functional-programming, type-inference

The codes below works well

```
List("ios","android","wm").exists(x =>"ios ok".contains(x))
```

However, if I add the parameter type in the anonymous function like this, it complains `type mismatch`:

```
scala> List("ios","android","wm").exists(x: String => "ios ok".contains(x))
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but string literal found.
       List("ios","android","wm").exists(x: String => "ios ok".contains(x))
                                                      ^
```

If I use `_` instead of `x`, it doesn't compile either:

```
scala>List("ios","android","wm").exists(_ =>"ios ok".contains(_))
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => "ios ok".<contains: error>(x$2))
```

Does anyone have ideas about this? 
Is there any implicit type conversion happening in these codes?
And how could I use the parameter type explicityly here?

Comment: Include the error in the post

Comment: It works if you use `exists((x: String) =>"ios ok".contains(x))`. I assume it is trying to parse a function type e.g. `x: String => SomeType`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm thinking when the compiler sees `:String => ...` it may be looking to complete a function type like `String => A`. This is getting triggered by the parentheses, because you'd normally have a typed anonymous function within curly braces.

These work:

```
List("ios","android","wm").exists((x: String) => x.contains(x))

List("ios","android","wm").exists { x: String => x.contains(x) }
```

And this last bit doesn't make any sense:

```
List("ios","android","wm").exists(_ =>"ios ok".contains(_))
```

The first `_` means you don't care what the element is, which is obviously not the case. So the compiler is looking to apply a function with two arguments with an argument list of one.

You want this instead:

```
List("ios","android","wm").exists("ios ok".contains(_))
```